# How can I find out which boss monsters I haven't killed yet?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have went online, mapped, and defeated all hinoxes, stone taluses, and moldugas in *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*. But when I go to Kilton to claim my reward, Kilton says I'm missing 39/40 hinoxes and stone taluses. So I re-mapped every monster, and all of them said they were defeated, and still no change. So I'm curious, is there a extra hinox and stone talus with the expansion pass DLC?

Comment: The only way you'll get an answer will be to post a comprehensive list of which monsters you have for anyone to work out what is missing.

Comment: [I found a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcBppPcTPiY) about someone playing in Master Mode and finding that Kilton wasn't giving them credit for defeating monsters. Are you also in Master Mode?

Answer (score 6):

It is a bit tough to tell you exactly which Boss Monster you are missing without knowing which monsters you have completed. However the following [interactive map](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/breath-of-the-wild-interactive-map/) might be useful to help you find out.

On the right side you can filter by the specific bosses you are looking to kill. Additionally when you click on the each bosses icon, there is a small info window that pops up the option to mark the Boss as completed/not completed. Then you can use the little gear in the top left corner to hide "completed" bosses, so you can track your progress as you go.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did. but this helps somewhat!